# Error while opening PDF file while creating it using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

Hello so i want to create a PDF file using python but when i open it, it shows me an error message that says [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPm2O.png)

My code:

```
import os
file = open("text.pdf", "x")
```

Comment: What are you writing to the text.pdf file? once you use the 'open' method, you have to write something to it before you can see any content

Comment: @Ashoka nothing, it is empty just for testing, i tried to open the file on Linux system and it opened no issue but in windows it showed me an error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are getting is because Adobe Acrobat cannot read an empty file. Same thing happens with Preview on Mac. You will have to write something to the file for these programs to read it.